# Custom domain Firebase cloudfuntions API

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have an Express API already in production using Firebase Cloud Functions but I need to add custom domain to it. I followed [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c93iGKyvh3o&t=128s) to create a custom domain for Cloud Functions using Firebase Hosting and end up with the following `firebase.json`

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "hosting": [{
    "site": "devbp",
    "target:":"devbp",
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

*index.ts*

```
import { functions } from './utils/exports-converter';
import App from './web-api/configs/app';

export * from './functions';
export * from './backup/schedules';
export * from './firestore-triggers/credits/credits-triggers'
export * from './schedules/transactions/aggregations-schedules';


export const api = functions.runWith({
    memory: '1GB',
    timeoutSeconds: 300
}).https.onRequest(App.express);
```

*exports-converter.ts*

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export { express, functions, admin };
```

*app.ts*

```
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import Routes from "./routes";
import { express } from "../../utils/exports-converter";

class App {
  public express: express.Application;
  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.init();
    this.mountRoutes();
  }
  private init() {
    const corsOptions = { origin: true };
    this.express.use(cors(corsOptions));
    this.express.use(bodyParser.raw());
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  }
  private mountRoutes() {
    Routes.mount(this.express);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the endpoints inside the api are not reachable, e.g. `GET devbp.web.app/api/user?id=123` which returns `Cannot GET /api/user`. This response indicates that Express is handling the requests (if not, the Hosting would throw a 404 page) but not as expected.

I believe that I'm missing something in my `firebase.json` because the same api, as said above, is currently in production.

Any thoughts on it?

Comment: Please edit the question to also show the function code that isn't working the way you expect.  We should have enough information to duplicate what you're observing.

Comment: @DougStevenson added a few more files, let me know if you need something else. Thank you

Comment: I don't see where you defined the express route that should handle the request as you expect.  I strongly suggest boiling this down to [minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), removing as much unnecessary code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_requests_to_function) ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#firebase-json_example) as well) hosting syntax is:

```
"hosting": {
...
}
```

while in the presented `firebase.json` you have `[{ ... }]`.
Try to remove square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I am following the logic, however I don't see any `new App` anywhere in the code. If I understand correctly if you do not create new `App` object you will not run it's constructor so express app will not be created.

2nd thing I think :) is that, again according to my understanding, there should be [Express get()](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.get) method called when GET request is called by http GET requst.

I found this [tutorial](https://wanago.io/2018/12/03/typescript-express-tutorial-routing-controllers-middleware/) it's not cloud function, however the logic is similar. New instance App is created and get method invoked.